# Equivalent of Yii CPasswordHelper?

Tags: php, yii, hash, passwords, password-encryption

I would like to store a hashed password in the database but by that time I haven't load Yii yet (due to my custom application installer). I want to know the equivalent of `CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($password);` in PHP. So far I have tried with the PHP `password_hash()` function like this:

```
password_hash(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'portal_password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 13));
```

The result comes out like: `$2y$13nhWAdiJeznsOqHph0yZaAOINqg14pGppOUqqyisaXsQuBtRKD076W` but when I tried to login with my original password, it failed. I notice that often the result of `CPasswordHelper::hashPassword` has `$2a$13` but mine has `$2y$13` prefix. Anyone could help? Thanks!

Comment: Both the `CPasswordHelper` class and the `password_hash()` function internally use the `crypt()` function to calculate the hash-value, that means they should be compatible. Actually you can pass the input directly to the password_hash() function, there is no need for sanitizing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my approach was working fine :) It is another irrelevant mistake somewhere else that cause the login failed. Hope someone might find this useful and thank you for your time!